# Mahout recommendation returns empty set

Tags: mahout

I am trying to run  KnnItemBasedRecommender using sample data "intro.csv" using the below code, however I am getting empty set as result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        DataModel model = NeuvidisData.convertToDataModel();

        //RecommenderEvaluator evaluator = new AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator();

        RecommenderBuilder recommenderBuilder = new RecommenderBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Recommender buildRecommender(DataModel model) {
                ItemSimilarity similarity = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(model);
                Optimizer optimizer = new ConjugateGradientOptimizer();
                return new KnnItemBasedRecommender(model, similarity, optimizer, 2);
            }
        };

        Recommender rec = recommenderBuilder.buildRecommender(model);
        List<RecommendedItem>  rcList  = rec.recommend(1, 2);

        for(RecommendedItem item:rcList)
        {
            System.out.println("item:");
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
                ItemSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(dataModel);
                Optimizer optimizer =  new ConjugateGradientOptimizer();
                Recommender recommender = new KnnItemBasedRecommender(dataModel, similarity, optimizer, 5);
```

Used PearsonCorrelationSimilarity instead of LogLikelihoodSimilarity.

This solution may work for a specific set of data. So, this solution is based on your data set.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because your data is too small or sparse to make recommendations for user 1 using this algorithm. Without the data it's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have uploaded data file and here is the link (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-TfUyCFoQ_3X0kwN3ZQeDlMdTA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I tried with  KnnItemBasedRecommender with a different data set and I found that the result depends on how DataModel is built. There are no results when I am using LogLikelihoodSimilarity whereas PearsonCorrelationSimilarity is working fine. Please through some light.

Comment: hope you are able to access data that was uploaded. Please let me know if you need any more inputs. Thank you in advance.